# ASP.NET OnClick event compilation error

Tags: asp.net, events

I'm modifying nopCommerce internet shopping software and I've a strange looking compilation error..

in file : CheckoutShipping.aspx I have:

```
<div class="button">
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnNextStep" Text="<% $NopResources:Checkout.NextButton %>"
                CssClass="newaddressnextstepbutton" ValidationGroup="EnterAddress"  OnClick="btnA"/>
</div>
```

and in CheckoutShipping.aspx.cs :

```
protected void btnA(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (Page.IsValid)
    {

        ctrlCheckoutBillingAddress.SelectCurrentAddress();
        ctrlCheckoutShippingAddress.SelectCurrentAddress();

        if (!this.OnePageCheckout)
            Response.Redirect("~/checkoutshippingmethod.aspx");
    }
}
```

I get:

> Compiler Error Message: CS1061:
>   'ASP.checkoutshippingaddress_aspx'
>   does not contain a definition for
>   'btnA' and no extension method 'btnA'
>   accepting a first argument of type
>   'ASP.checkoutshippingaddress_aspx'
>   could be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 28:  Line 29:          Line 30:
>   "
>   Line 31:
>   CssClass="newaddressnextstepbutton"
>   ValidationGroup="EnterAddress" 
>   OnClick="btnA"/> Line 32:

I've double checked the if class name & code file in aspx and aspx.cs files match(and they do).

Removing the OnClick part of the button declaration in aspx file (or changing it to ie. OnClick="Page_Load") helps.

What might be the reason for this? Do I have to register my functions somewhere?

Comment: web application or web site? if the former, check the page.aspx.designer file (to make sure delegate has been created). if the latter - you have to manually assign the delegate (i believe)

Comment: I've been playing with asp.net for a while, but I wasn't aware that there are two models (web app and website). I can't really figure out which one is in use, but I was opening the project by Open->Website->Local IIS. What is more partial compilation is possible so I think this is Website project. Can you explain more about the delegate? I know for sure I was missing declaration of button in .designer.cs file, but without OnClick it compiled anyway. I don't know what's happening here..

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error...

The inherit="" matched the filename, tried to change the properties of button from OnClick to OnClientClick.. and vice versa nothing worked..

**The simple solution which worked for me was, changing the CodeBehind to CodeFile...**

Answer (score 0):

Remove event name using property window and addit again that would help some times
or just remove it and addit with a defferent name 
I hope that would works

So as it still has happend

try to do it programatically I mean remove the event from htmls
and add it in your page load

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ...
         btnA.Click += new EventHandler(btnA_Click);
        ...
    }

    void btnA_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //you stuff here//


    }
```

Hope it works :)

Comment: It seems I've found the solution.. The method that I was referring to had errors and I assume asp.net compiler has some strange configuration that it was using previously built version. I downloaded a version of the shop with full sources, did the changes and then VS was able to show me what's wrong.

Comment: I was wrong. The problem is not solved. It works on iis dev server but not on real IIS.

Comment: oom its more complicated then :(

Comment: Please rechek my answer I have updated for u and hope it works